# Hiding the KeyWindow to cause a blank screenshot to be taken

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am trying to prevent the Apple implemmntation of taking a screenshot of the current screen contents when an app suspends into the background. I have found a piece of code that sort of works but it comes with a catch. What it does is that it clears the keywindow on the screen so when the snapshot is taken, it is of a blank screen. This is the code snippet for the functionality:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [ UIApplication sharedApplication ].keyWindow.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [ UIApplication sharedApplication ].keyWindow.hidden = YES;
}
```

The trouble with the above code is that when the app returns to the foreground, the view is gone as it has become hidden and i cannot unhide it with a simple

```
[ UIApplication sharedApplication ].keyWindow.hidden = NO;
```

in the applicationWillEnterForeground method of the app delegate. Does anyone know of a way to regain back the hidden view once i have hidden it in the background methods? Right now it is a black screen as the view has been hidden. What exactly happens when you hide a keywindow before going to background and then coming back. is that keywindow you hid before no longer the keywindow? Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Comment: What "screen shot" are you talking about? You mean the way a window is restored when it reopens? What behavior do you want to see?

Comment: I essentially want a blank screen cleared of all contents to be the one that shows for a split second (the snapshot iOS takes upon background activation) when the app returns. By default this snapshot is the last screen before app goes into background. I want this last screen to be devoid of all content before apple can take its snapshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just made a demo project and was able to reproduce your issue. Indeed, the `keyWindow` property of the application is `nil` when `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is called.

Many times, your application's delegate will have a reference to its window - this is usually the Xcode default template for many applications. I was able to resolve the issue by calling

```
self.window.hidden = NO;
```

Instead of `[UIApplication sharedApplication.keyWindow.hidden = NO;`. Assuming that, like most of the templates, your application delegate has a window reference.

Another alternative that worked for me is to call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`.

All this was done on the iOS 6 simulator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where are you calling this exactly?

Comment: I tried to put this in the applicationWillEnterForeground method of the app delegate and i dont see the same view as when the app was sent to the background. It returns with another view. In my case, when i press homebutton on my login page, it returns the view after the user presses login and logs on successfully :s

Comment: I put it in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` - where you were setting the `hidden` property before if I'm not mistaken. Do you create a new window? Doing anything with the root view controller? It worked completely fine for me but of course this was with a single view with just a green screen.

Comment: I actually might be doing that somewhere. Is there a way to make the key window the exact same window as the last window active before going to background.

Comment: If you keep a reference to that window in the application delegate, then it would be like `[self.otherWindow makeKeyAndVisible]` or `self.otherWindow.hidden = NO`.

Comment: is there a way to just assign the reference to the keywindow that i hide in the background method? and then access that window and make it key and visible in the return to foreground method

Comment: Have you tried setting the reference when you hide the key window going to the background? Something like `self.lastKeyWindow = application.keyWindow` I don't know if that would work with your window configuration or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17258/discussion-between-john-baum-and-carl-veazey)

Comment: The only thing that worked for me (on iOS7) to get the keyWindow to show again after hiding it was to call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];